# With File Vault ON are time machine backups encrypted?

Tags: backup, time-machine, encryption, filevault

I have been using time machine to back up to a wireless external drive since I got my mac. Today I used filevault to encrypt my hard drive.

- Will this affect how Time Machine backs up my files?
- Will the new backups be encrypted on the external drive?

I am running Lion on the mac.

I found this on an apple support page - http://docs.info.apple.com/article.html?path=Mac/10.6/en/21241.html

'If you must back up to a network or external disk that’s not under your control, you can turn on FileVault to encrypt data stored in your home directory. **This data will also be encrypted in the backup**. However, Time Machine will perform backups only when you are logged out of your user account.'

How can I check to see if the Time Machine backups are actually encrypted?

Comment: Note that the Apple document you linked applies to version 10.6.  FileVault has been completely changed in 10.7, so its descriptions no longer apply.

Answer (score 19):

No, the backups will not be encrypted automatically, but it's very easy to enable for directly attached disks. Just check "Encrypt Backup Disk" in the Time Machine disk selection settings.

[image]

If you're backing up to another Mac, you can use Disk Utility on that Mac to erase non-boot drives and put an encrypted partition on them:

[image]

Comment: Is this only possible for direct-attached disk? I have remote TM backups to another Mac happening and that option is greyed out, un-selectable.

Comment: @IanC. That would be my guess. If you are backing up to another Mac, you can always encrypt the disk manually with Disk Utility

Answer (score 7):

## No.

Time Machine backups are **not encrypted by default**. You have to **opt-in**. The configuration is easy if the backup drive is connected via USB/Firewire. If the backup drive is connected by Ethernet/Wi-Fi, the process of setting up Time Machine is more complicated.

#### **Connected via USB/Firewire**

Select the option in **System Preferences → Time Machine → Select Disk**

#### **Connected via Ethernet/Wi-Fi**

Basically, you need to manually create an encrypted sparse bundle on the external drive to which you will back up.

> 1. Figure out the name of your computer (and make sure it doesn’t contain spaces) in **System Preferences → Sharing**
> 2. Figure out the address of your main ethernet card. Type in the `Terminal.app` located at `/Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app`
>
>    ```
>    ifconfig en1 | grep ether
>    ```
>
>    MacbookAir: `en0` is Wi-Fi 
>      Other Macs: `en0` is Ethernet and `en1` is Wi-Fi
>
>    Write down the address for later use.
> 3. Open `Disk Utility.app` and create a **new image**:
>
>    [image]
>
>    **a)** *Save As:* ComputerName_EthernetAddress (without ":")
>
>    **b)** *Name:* ComputerName
>
>    **c)** *Size:* Choose a custom size.
>
>    **d)** *Format:* Mac OSX Extended (Journaled)
>
>    **e)** *Encryption:* Choose what you prefer. 128-bit is faster
>
>    **f)** *Partitions:* Single Partition, Apple Partition Map
>
>    **g)** *Image Format:* sparse bundle disk image
> 4. Open `Keychain Access.app` and move the password from your personal keychain (**login**) to the **system** keychain.
> 5. Start to backup!
>
> [[source: Mac OSX Lion Secure Backup to Time Capsule with size limit](http://michaelnozbe.com/mac-osx-lion-secure-backup-to-time-capsule-wi)]

I've used this solution for wireless encrypted backups in Lion myself for a while. However, ***it's quite slow.***

Therefore, you should backup less often and allow it enough time to finish. You can use a free tool such as the **[TimeMachineEditor](http://timesoftware.free.fr/timemachineeditor/)** to perform backups at custom time intervals or calendar events.